# streamlit add a fixed index column on the left

Tags: python, ag-grid, streamlit, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I've built an app using streamlit to aggregate and display a table with multiple filters. The dashboard can be found as this [image: the dashboard].

The only thing I want is to add a fixed index column (can be as a picture) on the left hand side with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and ensure the index is not changed after sorting by other columns.

I'm using st_aggrid: I can add index column, but this index will be linked to specific dealer name and move dynamically after sorting (by other columns). For example, BNP might be ranked as 3rd after sorting by "covered", I want to have it indexed as 3 not with 1 (as the df carries it forward).

Let me know if it is still not clear. Any solutions will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.